# Rendering a SceneKit scene to video output

Tags: ios, macos, video, rendering, scenekit

As a primarily high-level/iOS dev, I'm interested in using SceneKit for animation projects.

I've been having fun with SceneKit for some months now, despite it obviously being designed for 'live' interaction, I would find it incredibly useful to be able to 'render' an SKScene to video. Currently, I've been using Quicktime's screen recorder to capture video output, but (of course) the frame-rate drops in doing so. Is there an alternative that allows a scene to be rendered at its own pace and outputted as a smooth video file?

I understand this is unlikely to be possible... Just thought I'd ask in case I was missing something lower-level!

Comment: Which option did you use? Were you able to find something that also rendered video as if shot from a moving camera node?

Answer (score 8):

You could use an SCNRenderer to render to a CGImage offscreen, then add the CGImage to a video stream using AVFoundation.

I wrote this Swift extension for rendering into a CGImage.

```
public extension SCNRenderer {

    public func renderToImageSize(size: CGSize, floatComponents: Bool, atTime time: NSTimeInterval) -> CGImage? {

        var thumbnailCGImage: CGImage?

        let width = GLsizei(size.width), height = GLsizei(size.height)
        let samplesPerPixel = 4

        #if os(iOS)
            let oldGLContext = EAGLContext.currentContext()
            let glContext = unsafeBitCast(context, EAGLContext.self)

            EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(glContext)
            objc_sync_enter(glContext)
        #elseif os(OSX)
            let oldGLContext = CGLGetCurrentContext()
            let glContext = unsafeBitCast(context, CGLContextObj.self)

            CGLSetCurrentContext(glContext)
            CGLLockContext(glContext)
        #endif

        // set up the OpenGL buffers
        var thumbnailFramebuffer: GLuint = 0
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &thumbnailFramebuffer)
        glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), thumbnailFramebuffer); checkGLErrors()

        var colorRenderbuffer: GLuint = 0
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer)
        glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), colorRenderbuffer)
        if floatComponents {
            glRenderbufferStorage(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RGBA16F), width, height)
        } else {
            glRenderbufferStorage(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RGBA8), width, height)
        }
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), colorRenderbuffer); checkGLErrors()

        var depthRenderbuffer: GLuint = 0
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer)
        glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), depthRenderbuffer)
        glRenderbufferStorage(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24), width, height)
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), depthRenderbuffer); checkGLErrors()

        let framebufferStatus = Int32(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)))
        assert(framebufferStatus == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        if framebufferStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE {
            return nil
        }

        // clear buffer
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)); checkGLErrors()

        // render
        renderAtTime(time); checkGLErrors()

        // create the image
        if floatComponents { // float components (16-bits of actual precision)

            // slurp bytes out of OpenGL
            typealias ComponentType = Float

            var imageRawBuffer = [ComponentType](count: Int(width * height) * samplesPerPixel * sizeof(ComponentType), repeatedValue: 0)
            glReadPixels(GLint(0), GLint(0), width, height, GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_FLOAT), &imageRawBuffer)

            // flip image vertically — OpenGL has a different 'up' than CoreGraphics
            let rowLength = Int(width) * samplesPerPixel
            for rowIndex in 0..<(Int(height) / 2) {
                let baseIndex = rowIndex * rowLength
                let destinationIndex = (Int(height) - 1 - rowIndex) * rowLength

                swap(&imageRawBuffer[baseIndex..<(baseIndex + rowLength)], &imageRawBuffer[destinationIndex..<(destinationIndex + rowLength)])
            }

            // make the CGImage
            var imageBuffer = vImage_Buffer(
                data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(imageRawBuffer),
                height: vImagePixelCount(height),
                width: vImagePixelCount(width),
                rowBytes: Int(width) * sizeof(ComponentType) * samplesPerPixel)

            var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(
                bitsPerComponent: UInt32(sizeof(ComponentType) * 8),
                bitsPerPixel: UInt32(sizeof(ComponentType) * samplesPerPixel * 8),
                colorSpace: nil, // defaults to sRGB
                bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.FloatComponents.rawValue),
                version: UInt32(0),
                decode: nil,
                renderingIntent: kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

            var error: vImage_Error = 0
            thumbnailCGImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&imageBuffer, &format, nil, nil, vImage_Flags(kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole), &error)!.takeRetainedValue()

        } else { // byte components

            // slurp bytes out of OpenGL
            typealias ComponentType = UInt8

            var imageRawBuffer = [ComponentType](count: Int(width * height) * samplesPerPixel * sizeof(ComponentType), repeatedValue: 0)
            glReadPixels(GLint(0), GLint(0), width, height, GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), &imageRawBuffer)

            // flip image vertically — OpenGL has a different 'up' than CoreGraphics
            let rowLength = Int(width) * samplesPerPixel
            for rowIndex in 0..<(Int(height) / 2) {
                let baseIndex = rowIndex * rowLength
                let destinationIndex = (Int(height) - 1 - rowIndex) * rowLength

                swap(&imageRawBuffer[baseIndex..<(baseIndex + rowLength)], &imageRawBuffer[destinationIndex..<(destinationIndex + rowLength)])
            }

            // make the CGImage
            var imageBuffer = vImage_Buffer(
                data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(imageRawBuffer),
                height: vImagePixelCount(height),
                width: vImagePixelCount(width),
                rowBytes: Int(width) * sizeof(ComponentType) * samplesPerPixel)

            var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(
                bitsPerComponent: UInt32(sizeof(ComponentType) * 8),
                bitsPerPixel: UInt32(sizeof(ComponentType) * samplesPerPixel * 8),
                colorSpace: nil, // defaults to sRGB
                bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue),
                version: UInt32(0),
                decode: nil,
                renderingIntent: kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

            var error: vImage_Error = 0
            thumbnailCGImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&imageBuffer, &format, nil, nil, vImage_Flags(kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole), &error)!.takeRetainedValue()
        }

        #if os(iOS)
            objc_sync_exit(glContext)
            if oldGLContext != nil {
                EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(oldGLContext)
            }
        #elseif os(OSX)
            CGLUnlockContext(glContext)
            if oldGLContext != nil {
                CGLSetCurrentContext(oldGLContext)
            }
        #endif

        return thumbnailCGImage
    }
}


func checkGLErrors() {
    var glError: GLenum
    var hadError = false
    do {
        glError = glGetError()
        if glError != 0 {
            println(String(format: "OpenGL error %#x", glError))
            hadError = true
        }
    } while glError != 0
    assert(!hadError)
}
```

Comment: This looks amazing! Would this work if we wanted to capture video as if from a moving camera node? In other words, the goal is to simulate a video of a camera node exploring a SCNView.

Comment: Yah, this renders from the renderer’s current scene.pointOfView node, so you can just move that node and/or change its SCNCamera in between frames to animate.

Comment: Thanks @WilShipley! If you don't mind, would like to ask you something over email. What's the best way to reach you?

Comment: wjs at delicious-monster dot com

Answer (score 4):

** This is the answer for SceneKit using Metal.

** Warning: This may not be a proper method for App Store. But it's working.

Step 1: Swap the method of nextDrawable of CAMetalLayer with a new one using swizzling.
Save the CAMetalDrawable for each render loop.

```
extension CAMetalLayer {
  public static func setupSwizzling() {
    struct Static {
      static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
      let copiedOriginalSelector = #selector(CAMetalLayer.orginalNextDrawable)
      let originalSelector = #selector(CAMetalLayer.nextDrawable)
      let swizzledSelector = #selector(CAMetalLayer.newNextDrawable)

      let copiedOriginalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, copiedOriginalSelector)
      let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
      let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

      let oldImp = method_getImplementation(originalMethod)
      method_setImplementation(copiedOriginalMethod, oldImp)
      method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
  }


  func newNextDrawable() -> CAMetalDrawable? {
    let drawable = orginalNextDrawable()
    // Save the drawable to any where you want
    AppManager.sharedInstance.currentSceneDrawable = drawable
    return drawable
  }

  func orginalNextDrawable() -> CAMetalDrawable? {
    // This is just a placeholder. Implementation will be replaced with nextDrawable.
    return nil
  }
}
```

Step 2:
Setup the swizzling in AppDelegate: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  CAMetalLayer.setupSwizzling()
  return true
}
```

Step 3:
Disable framebufferOnly for your's SCNView's CAMetalLayer (In order to call getBytes for MTLTexture)

```
if let metalLayer = scnView.layer as? CAMetalLayer {
  metalLayer.framebufferOnly = false
}
```

Step 4:
In your SCNView's delegate (SCNSceneRendererDelegate), play with the texture

```
func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
    if let texture = AppManager.sharedInstance.currentSceneDrawable?.texture where !texture.framebufferOnly {
      AppManager.sharedInstance.currentSceneDrawable = nil
      // Get image from texture
      let image = texture.toImage()
      // Use the image for video recording
    }
}

extension MTLTexture {
  func bytes() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> {
    let width = self.width
    let height   = self.height
    let rowBytes = self.width * 4
    let p = malloc(width * height * 4) //Beware for memory leak
    self.getBytes(p, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, fromRegion: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height), mipmapLevel: 0)
    return p
  }

  func toImage() -> UIImage? {
    var uiImage: UIImage?
    let p = bytes()
    let pColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let rawBitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue
    let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: rawBitmapInfo)

    let selftureSize = self.width * self.height * 4
    let rowBytes = self.width * 4
    let provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, p, selftureSize, {_,_,_ in })!

    if let cgImage = CGImageCreate(self.width, self.height, 8, 32, rowBytes, pColorSpace, bitmapInfo, provider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault) {
      uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    }
    return uiImage
  }

  func toImageAsJpeg(compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
  }
}
```

Step 5 (Optional):
You may need to confirm the drawable at CAMetalLayer you are getting is your target. (If more then one CAMetalLayer at the same time)

Comment: It works perfectly on some of my devices. But on some of them it crashes inside SceneKit framework with message "Either set rendertargets in RenderPassDescriptor or set renderTargetWidth and renderTargetHeight.". But seems like your application Facemous is able to generate correct video. Can you help me with this issue? I can create a sample for you.

Answer (score 1):

It would actually be pretty easy! Here's a pseudo code of how I would do it (on the SCNView):

```
int numberOfFrames = 300;
int currentFrame = 0;
int framesPerSecond = 30;

-(void) renderAFrame{
    [self renderAtTime:1/framesPerSecond];

    NSImage *frame = [self snapshot];

    // save the image with the frame number in the name such as f_001.png

    currentFrame++;

    if(currentFrame < numberOfFrames){
        [self renderAFrame];
    }

}
```

It will output you a sequence of images, rendered at 30 frames per second, that you can import in any editing software and convert to video.

Comment: did this work for you? we tried something similar but changing the scene between frames (e.g., placing nodes or moving the camera) was not synchronized with the screenshot/snapshot, meaning you would create a block but it wasn't reflected in the next snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way with a SKVideoNode you put into a SKScene that you use to map as a SCNode's SCMaterial.Diffuse.Content (Hope that's clear ;) )

```swift
player = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL!)
let videoSpriteKitNodeLeft = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player)
let videoNodeLeft = SCNNode()
let spriteKitScene1 = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1280 * screenScale, height: 1280 * screenScale))
spriteKitScene1.shouldRasterize = true

videoNodeLeft.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 30)
spriteKitScene1.scaleMode = .AspectFit
videoSpriteKitNodeLeft.position = CGPoint(
  x: spriteKitScene1.size.width / 2.0, y: spriteKitScene1.size.height / 2.0)
videoSpriteKitNodeLeft.size = spriteKitScene1.size

spriteKitScene1.addChild(videoSpriteKitNodeLeft)

videoNodeLeft.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene1
videoNodeLeft.geometry?.firstMaterial?.doubleSided = true

// Flip video upside down, so that it's shown in the right position
var transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(M_PI), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
transform = SCNMatrix4Translate(transform, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0)

videoNodeLeft.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(M_PI_2), 0.0, -1.0, 0.0)
videoNodeLeft.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = transform

videoNodeLeft.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(videoNodeLeft)
```

I've extracted the code from a github project of mine for a 360 video player using SceneKit to play a video inside a 3D Sphere: https://github.com/Aralekk/simple360player_iOS/blob/master/simple360player/ViewController.swift

I hope this helps !

Arthur