# SceneKit and SCNBox: use one generic texture but change appearance with different colors?

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnnode

Is it possible with SCNBox to use different colors for the material and then overlay a grainy texture? The net effect lets you effectively create an infinite number of different colored textures while only using a single image.

Is this possible with SceneKit?

This question is different from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509092/scnbox-different-colour-or-texture-on-each-face), as the solutions suggest different images for different colored textures.

Answer (score 3):

is the [`multiply`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterial_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterial/multiply) material property what you're looking for?

You can use your image for the `diffuse` material property, and then set a color to `multiply` to tint that image.

Comment: Thanks so much, will try it! Happened to check your profile since you answer so many SceneKit answers (thanks for sharing your knowledge) ... and saw you work at Apple. :) Would you recommend this as the best way to render SceneKit to video? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060465/rendering-a-scenekit-scene-to-video-output)? Would be cool to have video for sharing creations with others. Either way, thanks for helping!